# "declare function" not working in groupplots?

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, calc, arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style = {group size = 1 by 2},
                width=15cm, height=4.5cm,
                xmin=0, xmax=100, 
                ymin=0, ymax=12,
                xlabel = {x},
                ylabel = {y},
                grid,
                declare function = {r1(\x)=2*\x/10 - \x/800*\x;},
                declare function = {r2(\x)=2*\x - \x/10*\x;},
            ]
            \nextgroupplot[
                % declare function = {r1(\x)=2*\x/10 - \x/800*\x;},
                % declare function = {r2(\x)=2*\x - \x/10*\x;},
            ]
            \addplot[ultra thick, red,  domain=0:10] {r2(x)};
            \addplot[thick, dotted, red,  domain=10:20, forget plot] {r2(x)};

            \nextgroupplot[
                % declare function = {r1(\x)=2*\x/10 - \x/800*\x;},
                % declare function = {r2(\x)=2*\x - \x/10*\x;},
            ]

            \addplot[ultra thick, cyan,  domain=0:80] {r1(x)};
            \addplot[thick, dotted, cyan,  domain=80:100, forget plot] {r1(x)};
        \end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It will fail to compile with

```
buggp.tex|18 error| Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/declare function', to which you passed 'r1(\x )=2*\x /10 - \x /800*\x ;', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
[...]
```

But if I move the funcion definitions in the individual `\nextgroupplot` as int the code above (commented), it will work ok, and ouptut the correct result:

[image]

Is this a bug/feature of `groupplots` or there is something I am doing wrong here? I would like to share the definitions for all the graphs in the group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`declare function` belongs to `/tikz` I think, so `/tikz/declare function` works. I haven't tried figuring out what happens, probably the `groupplots` environment doesn't look in `/tikz`.

You only need one by the way, multiple functions can be defined in the same. Alternatively, you could use `\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function=..` or `\tikzset{declare function=..` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, calc, arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style = {group size = 1 by 2},
                width=15cm, height=4.5cm,
                xmin=0, xmax=100, 
                ymin=0, ymax=12,
                xlabel = {x},
                ylabel = {y},
                grid,
                /tikz/declare function = {
                  r1(\x)=2*\x/10 - \x/800*\x;
                  r2(\x)=2*\x - \x/10*\x;
                },
            ]
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot[ultra thick, red,  domain=0:10] {r2(x)};
            \addplot[thick, dotted, red,  domain=10:20, forget plot] {r2(x)};

            \nextgroupplot    
            \addplot[ultra thick, cyan,  domain=0:80] {r1(x)};
            \addplot[thick, dotted, cyan,  domain=80:100, forget plot] {r1(x)};
        \end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. Is there a hat for the fastest answer in the West?